# Filtering by Cell Background Color SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data sent that I managed to change the background color for values of 100% to Red for bad, and values under 85% to Yellow for good. The values in between have been blank. I am attempting to add a filter to the data that would make the report show only the colored cells(in other words values that are over 100% and under 85%). I can mange to put a filter that shows one or the other but not both. Any ideas how to add AND statements so the filter shows both requirements ?

Comment: Could you show the tablix that you are using and the groupings you have used?
Also can you show us the code you have tried before?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Filter section of the charts and datasets is somewhat limited. You can add multiple filters which will work as an AND but there's no OR functionality, which is what you need for find records that are over 100% OR under 85%.

The usual workaround is to use an IIF with the OR in it for the Filter's Expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!PERCENT.Value >= 1 OR Fields!PERCENT.Value <= .85, 1, 0)
```

Then have the type as Integer and Value as 1.

You could also use a SWITCH statement which is helpful if you have more conditions:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!PERCENT.Value >= 1, 1, 
        Fields!PERCENT.Value <= .85, 1, 
        1 = 1, 0)
```

The SWITCH will evaluate the conditions one at a time and return the value if the condition is true.